SELECT COUNT with limit rows
We want to check table rows count firstly and based on the number decide what should be done. As we have a logic that if table rows more than certain number we will try with different logic.
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1.  

is simplest however it could be very expensive if table is huge.
So we try following logic in Oracle
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000000;

If above query return 1000000 ,then we know this table bigger than 1000,000. then We will use different way to process it.
Now we want similiar logic for SQL Server as well but i didnt see any easy way to do it.
SQL Server offers a TOP statement however it dont work like following:
SELECT COUNT( TOP 1000000 *) FROM Table1 

Anyone get idea?

Just select the total count and then make your decision

As I said , SELECT COUNT() FROM TABLE is simple but it could be extremely expensive. For example, If we know this table row more than 1M , then we will use Temp table with bulk approach to process data. So 1M is Maximum Count number we start use different logic. But if this table is 500M? SELECT COUNT() to return 500M will take more than 1 minutes to return. That why I ask is there any easy way. In Oracle or Postgresql they provide a simple way such as LIMIT or ROWNUM to control only return limit rows from query,

Have you actually tested that performance? I've used count * on very large tables with no issue before

You can query the metadata?

https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way

To simply answer the question how to combine TOP and COUNT: Just use a subquery as shown in this sample fiddle. If the goal is to improve the performance, then query the metadata as already mentioned.

Check sys.partitions for the size, it avoids scanning the table

If you insist on avoiding the metadata tables, you can use a TOP N option inside a subselect as follows:
DECLARE @RowCountLimited INT = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 101 *
        FROM TableA
    ) S
)
  
SELECT  @RowCountLimited

Alternately you can use an EXISTS() together with the ORDER BY ... OFFSET ... FETCH ... syntax. This requires an ORDER BY, but if you choose an indexed column or the PK, no sort operation is generated in the plan.
DECLARE @RowCountIsMoreThan100 BIT = CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableB
    WHERE IsActive = 1
    ORDER BY IsActive  -- Should be an indexed column or PK
    OFFSET 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  
SELECT @RowCountIsMoreThan100

Either of the above can include a WHERE condition (with an appropriate supporting index).
See this db<>fiddle for a demo with execution plans.
The plans show that only a limited number of rows are actually read, as is intended. If the table is indexed, SQL Server will tend to select the smallest (fewest bytes per row) usable index to perform the operation. This will still be slower than calculating the count from metadata.

In some cases when:

you want just a sniffing about the size
has no delete operation OR only logical exclusion (active=false)
and not much transaction process (rollback affect identity and sequence)

You can use MAX function
SELECT MAX(ID) AS total FROM TableA 

OR
SELECT TOP 1 ID AS TOTAL FROM TableA ORDER BY ID DESC;


It's unlikely the id will represent the number of rows, deletes make gaps as does the identity column itself.
